# I keep getting Metamask 429 Error on my Dapp

Tags: metamask, react, moralis, arbitrum

I'm using `react-moralis` to enabled web3 access on my Dapp. For the application to function, we are constantly reading from the blockchain and, of course, often writing to it as well. We have tried to limit our calls to the blockchain, but the reality is we can only limit it to once or twice every time the state changes on the blockchain. As a result, when purposely triggering these state changes 50-60 times, our application breaks with the error:

```
MetaMask - RPC Error: Non-200 status code: '429'
```

So I'm pretty sure this has to do with the Metamask RPC url I have for the current network I'm connected to (Arbitrum Goerli atm) having a request limit of approx 60 a minute. My question is, how can I best avoid this as a Dapp developer? Must I rely on a centralized database to store my data and retrieve data from the blockchain using an independent node or is there a way to avoid this Metamask error and from the blockchain regularly without issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using batch calls but from a requirements point of view if you don't have an actual need to get information i/o at that rate consider reducing the amount of calls made.

Answer (score 0):

If you get it on your Moralis API calls it's most likely because you are on a Moralis free plan and are hitting the requests per second max which is limited to 25 compute units per second.

You can either spread out your calls more or transition to a paid plan.